# ExtJs - Creating a Grid from records in a database

Tags: mysql, datagrid, extjs4

I'm using ExtJS 4.2 and I have some records in a MySql database. My question is: How can I create a grid that displays the records in the database?
I tried using ResultSet in a servlet to retrieve the records from the database, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

How can i populate the fields in the grid with the records in my database?
I'm new to ExtJS and I'm finding it difficult to come up with a solution for this. Does this have something to do with the `store` field? If so, how do i go about achieving the above said requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create store, bind to the grid and then load data from server. And sure you need backend for this **ExtJS4 do not provide any tools for working with databases**
For example( [taken from sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/grid/xml-grid.html) ):

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.define('Book',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            reader: 'xml'
        },
        fields: [
            // set up the fields mapping into the xml doc
            // The first needs mapping, the others are very basic
            {name: 'Author', mapping: '@author.name'},
            'Title', 'Manufacturer', 'ProductGroup'
        ]
    });

    // create the Data Store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Book',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            // load using HTTP
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'sheldon.xml',
            // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
            reader: {
                type: 'xml',
                // records will have an "Item" tag
                record: 'Item',
                idProperty: 'ASIN',
                totalRecords: '@total'
            }
        }
    });

    // create the grid
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {text: "Author", flex: 1, dataIndex: 'Author'},
            {text: "Title", width: 180, dataIndex: 'Title'},
            {text: "Manufacturer", width: 115, dataIndex: 'Manufacturer'},
            {text: "Product Group", width: 100, dataIndex: 'ProductGroup'}
        ],
        renderTo:'example-grid',
        width: 540,
        height: 200
    });
});
```

The main idea is - models are for defining structure of the record and validation(read about it [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model)), stores - for storing and fetching(by parsing response from server or local defined data) records that match model structure([Basic store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store)) and finally grid handles some events(like "load" or "refresh") and updating rows based on grids column defenition([docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel))